# Clear value in ID after failed upsert

Tags: apex

I have two upsert statements which insert/update a parent and the child records.  The parent may be a new record (created from an overridden "new" visualforce page) or an existing record (overridden "edit" visualforce page, same page).  The problem I'm running into is that for a new record, after I upsert the parent it gets a new ID (as it should) but then if the upsert of the children fail (because it triggers validation rule) the parent still has the ID, even when I roll back with a savepoint.  Then when I clear out the errors, the upsert of the parent fails because it still has the ID from the first failed upsert which is no longer valid.

How can I clear that ID if the upserts fail so that the database will give the parent a new id after a successful upsert?

My controller (the issues comes on the Save_PA method):

```
public with sharing class PayrollAuthorization_extn {

public list <PA_Distribution__c> PayrollDistributionList {get; set;}
public Payroll_Authorization__c PA;
public String rowID {get;set;}
public List<PA_Distribution__c> delProgramList {get; set;}
public ID TempPA_ID;

public PayrollAuthorization_extn(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

PA = (Payroll_Authorization__c)controller.getRecord();
If (PA == null) PA = new Payroll_Authorization__c();
    PayrollDistributionList = [Select Id, Name, Program__c,Payroll_Authorization__c, Program_Percent__c, Program_as_Number__c,  Program_ID__c
        From PA_Distribution__c 
        Where Payroll_Authorization__r.id =: controller.getId()
        ];  
delProgramList = new List<PA_Distribution__c>();            
}

public void addRow(){
    PayrollDistributionList.add(new PA_Distribution__c( Payroll_Authorization__c = PA.id));
}

public PageReference SavePA (){
   Savepoint sp;  
    Try{
    sp = Database.setSavepoint();
    TempPA_ID = PA.id;
    upsert PA;
    for (PA_Distribution__c PD: PayrollDistributionList) {
        If (PD.Payroll_Authorization__c == null){
            PD.Payroll_Authorization__c = PA.Id;
            System.debug(PD);
        }
      }
    //System.debug ('PA_fromController following upsert ID is' + PA_fromController.id);

   upsert PayrollDistributionList;
   delete delProgramList;

    return (new ApexPages.StandardController(PA)).view();
    }
    Catch (Exception ex){
        Database.rollback(sp);
        PA.id = TempPA_ID;
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,ex.getMessage()));
    }
    return null;
}

public void deleteRow(){

    PA_Distribution__c del;

    Integer i = Integer.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RowID'));
        del= PayrollDistributionList[i];
        If (rowID != ''){    
          PayrollDistributionList.remove(i);
               If(del.Id <> null) delProgramList.add(del);

    }
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a duplicate of what you are about to upsert, using the method `deepClone(true)` for your list and the `clone(true)` for your sObject. and after success... assign them to the original if needed.

Like...

```
public PageReference SavePA (){
    Savepoint sp;
    try{
        sp = Database.setSavepoint();
        Payroll_Authorization__c clonePA = PA.clone(true);
        List<PA_Distribution__c> clonePayrollDistributionList = PayrollDistributionList.deepClone(true);
        upsert clonePA;
        for (PA_Distribution__c PD: clonePayrollDistributionList) {
            If (PD.Payroll_Authorization__c == null){
                PD.Payroll_Authorization__c = clonePA.Id;
                System.debug(PD);
            }
        }
        //System.debug ('PA_fromController following upsert ID is' + PA_fromController.id);

        upsert clonePayrollDistributionList;
        delete delProgramList;


        // assign to the originals
        PA = clonePA;
        PayrollDistributionList = clonePayrollDistributionList;
        return (new ApexPages.StandardController(PA)).view();
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        Database.rollback(sp);
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,ex.getMessage()));
    }
    return null;
}
```